# CSS Border Question

Tags: html, css, text, border

What is the element/attribute that would cause this effect to text and how would I achieve this in code? -

[image: Unknown Element/Attribute]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean by most browser's default stylesheet, it would be the [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset) element as the parent and [`legend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/legend) as the child.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfW3Y/).

Comment: Sorry wasn't what I wanted but did give me a new insight into this frameset tag. ** EDIT ** : Thanks this is what I wanted!!!

Answer (score 1):

The HTML legend tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp